# Get All Parents Info Up Until Specified Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, parents

I have this html codes example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="stophere">
               <h4 class="parentclass"> 
                <span class="target">Clicked</span>
               </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

From the html codes example above, I want to get all parents' tag name of class `target` (when receiving click event) down from div with id `stophere`.

I tried this code:

```
$(ev.target).parents()
            .map(function() {
            return this.tagName;
            })
            .get()
            .join( ", " );
```

But it includes all parents' tag names above `stophere`. While the result I want is only 1 `div` and 1 `h4`.

What is the correct way to get all parents of `target` down from `stophere`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`parentsUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) method for that

```
$(ev.target).parentsUntil($('#stophere').parent())
```

Note that it's non-inclusive, so we pass the parent of `#stophere` to include that element as well

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rpoLs1u1/)

Comment: Not sure why it is not working in my case using map and event handler. but working well in js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/32g5uhrm/1/

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim that this is a good solution, but can be used if adeneo's solution is failed in your situation like in my case.

This code is checking whether the traversing limit is containing that limit line itself or not, by using `find()` method:

```
    jQuery('html').on("click", function (ev) {
        var elemparentid = jQuery(ev.target).closest("[id]").attr("id");
        var thisparents = jQuery(ev.target).parents()
            .map(function () {
// check if traversing limit is a children of current element or not, by using find() method
            if (jQuery(this).find("#" + elemparentid).length < 1) {
                return this.tagName;
            }
        }).get()
            .join(", ");
        alert(thisparents);
    });
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oww4yfqb/)**